# fncychap messes up bookmarks

Tags: lyx, bookmarks, fncychap

When using `fncychap`, some of the bookmarks pointing to an appendix is linked to a random chapter. If I avoid using the package, which I am hoping not to, the bookmarks are all fine. I am using `report`.

The parts of the appendix marked as `chapter`, actually gets bookmarked to actual chapters, so Appendix A and Appendix B gets linked to Chapter 1 and Chapter 2

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I use LyX, and here is a file [bookmarks_error.lyx](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9Lnsj9U0mK8SVlvcjB4Smt1OUk)
Also, I use `\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}`

Comment: Please, make a minimal example showing the problem. In my test (some chapters and two appendices) I have none.

Comment: I updated the text. Only appendix content marked `chapter` (appendix A, B...) is broken.

Comment: Not in my experiment. Please, without some code exhibiting the problem, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two fixes:

- If you use `\addcontentsline` before a `\chapter`, make sure to end the page before, i.e. insert a page break (`\cleardoublepage`, `\clearpage`, you will find it in LyX in the Insert/ Formatting menu). And set an anchor using `\phantomsection` as TeX code.

[image: page break and anchor]

- The numbering of chapters restarts in the appendix, which can generate the same internal link names (`chapter.1` for Chapter 1, `chapter.1` for Chapter A). Use the `hyperref` option called `naturalnames` to avoid this, because then you would get the internal link name `chapter.A`. You will find it in Document Settings/ PDF Properties/ Hyperlinks:

[image: hyperlink options]

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a problem by taking the `\fncychap` before `\hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
```