# TOC link to figures/tables does not work

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, koma-script, scrbook, fncychap

There are quite a bit of related questions:

- [hyperref not working. It goes to wrong page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258969/hyperref-not-working-it-goes-to-wrong-page). Use `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.
- [Link of “List of figures” leads to Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394183/link-of-list-of-figures-leads-to-table-of-contents). Use `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.
- [Correct hyperlink to the index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/correct-hyperlink-to-the-index). Not sure...
- [KOMA book: correct hyperlink to the index?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/koma-book-correct-hyperlink-to-the-index). Use `index=totoc`.
- [Link to index in TOC points does not point to index, but to whatever is right before index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65255/link-to-index-in-toc-points-does-not-point-to-index-but-to-whatever-is-right-be). Use `\phantomsection` or `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.
- [Links do not lead to right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103123/links-do-not-lead-to-right-pages). Use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`. Put `hyperref` last.
- [Latex Table of Contents Links to Wrong Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782187/latex-table-of-contents-links-to-wrong-section). Use `\phantomsection` (optional `\newpage` before) and `\addcontentsline`, or `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.
- [Hyperref does not work for List of Fig/Tables and previous textblocks (Abstract etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249518/hyperref-does-not-work-for-list-of-fig-tables-and-previous-textblocks-abstract). Use `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.
- [fncychap messes up bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73514/fncychap-messes-up-bookmarks). Use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`.
- [fncychap and hyperref messes up page references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77886/fncychap-and-hyperref-messes-up-page-references). Use `\usepackage{hyperref}` after `\usepackage{fncychap}`.
- [wrong page numbering in the bibliography using fncychap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/wrong-page-numbering-in-the-bibliography-using-fncychap). Use `\phantomsection`.

However, after trying out many of the suggested solutions (which are sometimes contradictory) for a couple of hours, and still failing, I thought I post this here now as another question (and hopefully I can add the solution to this case later).

In earlier variants of my code, even the link to glossaries and bibliography was broken, but that seems to work now. In this latest version, everything seems to work, except the link to figures and tables.

Note that the code comes from a template for a PhD thesis, and in principle I think I should not change too much in there.

Example code, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% for original fncychap
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\makeatother

\title{Thesis}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}
...

\backmatter

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

For reference, my Latex version:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

I already tried multiple things, but maybe in the wrong combination, or wrong import order, or wrong options, or so.

- `\phantomsection` somewhat works, but it then links to the end of the previous chapter, not the beginning of the new chapter.
- `\usepackage{tocbibind}` (or with some of the options) does not seem to work.
  More specifically:

  - `\usepackage{tocbibind}` (without options) adds a "Contents" chapter (which I don't want) and breaks the bibliography chapter link in the TOC. The glossary link still works, and the list of tables/figures link still does not work.
  - `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` is like without options but without the extra "Contents" chapter.
  - `\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}` is just the same as `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. `notlof` or `notlot` does not seem to have an effect.
- `index=totoc` in the documentclass options ([via](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/koma-book-correct-hyperlink-to-the-index)) does not seem to have an effect.
- `\usepackage{nomencl}` (with variants of the options) does not seem to have an effect.

Probably relevant are also the `hyperref` options. I think I need to have `hypertexnames=false` in there, as this was in the original template like this. Also, changing this seems to break other things.

Also, in some places, it is stated that `hyperref` should come first. In other places, it is stated that it should come last. In yet other places, it is stated that `glossaries` should come after `hyperref`.

I noticed, the `\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}` seems to cause this. If I remove this, it works. However, I need to use it.
(Also, I noticed that the template comes with the `fncychap` v1.34 package. However, if I use the normal one (from Tex Live 2018), I get the same problem. In addition, maybe some `Class scrbook Error: undefined old font command \rm` error, but that is easy to work around, and not related here.)

---

**Edit**: After randomly trying around, after the answer from Ulrike Fischer, without really understanding what I'm doing, I added this (right after the last `\usepackage`):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@schapter[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
      \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter
      \xdef\@currentHref{\Hy@chapapp*.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
      \Hy@raisedlink{%
        \hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend
      }%
    \endgroup
    \H@old@schapter{#1}%
   }
\makeatother
```

(I got this code from my `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/hyperref.hak` file.)

And this seems to fix the problem... Maybe someone can explain why it works? Or if it really solves the problem, or maybe introduces other problems?

---

**Further edit**: In my `fncychap.sty`, I found this:

```
%%% Begin: To avoid problem with scrbook.cls (fncychap version 1.32)

%%OUT:
%\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
%                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
%                 \else
%                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
%                   \@afterheading
%                 \fi}

%%IN:
\def\@schapter#1{%
\if@twocolumn%
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
\else%
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
  \@afterheading%
\fi}

%%% End: To avoid problem with scrbook.cls (fncychap version 1.32)
```

If I just remove that, it also seems to fix my problem?
I wonder though, what is it what `fncychap` tried to fix here? I.e. what was meant by "avoid problem with scrbook.cls"?

---

As a side node, daleif argues in the comments that you better should avoid `fncychap` and `scrbook` if you can. `fncychap` was last updated in 2007.

Comment: Please reduce the example to only those pieces that are actually needed.

Comment: @daleif I reduced it further. Also I added a fix for some Tex Live versions and `fncychap`, it should compile now. Note that I want to have the glossaries in it, and also a table in it, because this combination is important. I don't want to fix the list of tables link but then introduce other problems in other parts.

Comment: The general idea is that you can trim things down to the minimal example that exhibits the problem (no bibliography, no glossary).  Then you can figure out why your TOC isn't linking to particular tables or figures.  Then you can put the fix into your actual project, and see if there is some new complication.  But there usually isn't.  (And if fncychap is contributing to the problem, that's only one extra line in your minimal example.)

Comment: You should probably drop `\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}` the hypertargets seems to work correctly when it is not loaded. When loaded things go wrong. Plus it has not been updated in 13 years.

Comment: Additionally load `glossaries` before `hyperref` (only `cleverref` needs to go after `hyperref`)

Comment: Ok, I cleaned it up, but I'm a bit afraid that the solution now might be invalid with the other things I removed (glossaries, bibliography, tables, figures, links, ...).

Comment: @daleif I **must** use that package `fncychap`, because this is the official PhD template, and I must not change it. However, I think I am allowed to patch any problems in that package.

Comment: Then you probably have to talk to the people who says you have to use such an archaic template using components that has not been updated in years.

Comment: @daleif But it should be possible to fix `fncychap`, right? I mean, I could also rephrase my question to "how to fix `fncychap`". Or just copy the relevant `fncychap` over directly to this question, and then not have that package anymore.

Comment: It cannot be your responsibility to patch a broken PhD template, it should be reported to your organisation that there are issues to be addressed with the template. Why are they mixing koma with fncychap in the first place. This does not seem to be a trustworthy template to begin with

Comment: I'd like to see the requirement that you **must** use fncychap and scrbook. At my department we have no such rules, only requirements on the contents

Comment: @daleif Instead of discussing with my university and/or supervisor about whether I can change it, and explaining them about the problems, maybe it is easier to just fix the problem? Also, even if I could avoid `fncychap` or `scrbook`, I still would be interested how to fix the problem, or understand the problem. Actually I already posted one possible solution. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Then think about the next student. Why should they have to go through the same thing

Comment: @daleif I still am interested in the basic problem itself, no matter the university politics. And maybe other people also get to the situation that they have to use `fncychap` and `scrbook`. I don't think it is helpful now to say that these better just should not be used. (Unless you maybe have a very simple way to replace them by sth else which will produce exactly the same output.) Or I mean, fair point, I will keep that in mind, and this is probably also good to know for future readers. However, I still would like to know how to solve it. Or it is not valid to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

scrbook contains patches that it executes after hyperref has been loaded. In this patch it reverts the definition of the chapter commands and so overwrites the patches from hyperref. scrbook obviously doesn't expect that the chapter commands have be changed by some other package.

You can try this:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,
enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrbook}
%disable scrbook patch:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\scr@chapter@after@hyperref@patch{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}


\usepackage[%
hypertexnames=false,%
bookmarks=true,%                   %%% generate bookmarks ...
bookmarksnumbered=true,%           %%% ... with numbers
]{hyperref}

\title{Thesis}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\backmatter

\listoffigures

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `LaTeX Error: \scr@chapter@after@hyperref@patch undefined.` for that. Am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: Then your system is older than mine and I can't help you ...

Comment: Actually, your answer lead me to a somewhat working solution now. I extended my question. Maybe you have an idea if this is a valid option?

Comment: it could work. it is more or less what hyperref does and what scrbook destroys.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest `fncychap` package [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap), and copy the `fncychap.sty` into the directory of your Latex code.

Open the file. You will find some code like this:

```
%%% Begin: To avoid problem with scrbook.cls (fncychap version 1.32)

%%OUT:
%\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
%                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
%                 \else
%                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
%                   \@afterheading
%                 \fi}

%%IN:
\def\@schapter#1{%
\if@twocolumn%
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
\else%
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
  \@afterheading%
\fi}

%%% End: To avoid problem with scrbook.cls (fncychap version 1.32)
```

Remove this code, or comment it out.

This seems to solve the problem.

`scrbook` has its own definition of `\@schapter` and this breaks it.